# Starting MongoDB as a service with auth

Tags: mongodb

I created a mongodb replicaset (using 3.2) and on each server, I set up MongoDB as a service

"C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.2\bin\mongod.exe" --config "C:\program files\mongodb\server\3.2\mongod.cfg" --service

So far so good. I recently set up users and need to set up MongoDB so that a user has to be supplied.  From what I've read, I would start mongodb with the --auth parameter.  However, since the service is already created, is there an equivalent in the config file?  Based on the [Configuration File Options Documentions](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/),   I have tried security.authorization set to enable

```
security:
    authorization: enabled
```

But when I restarted the service on both servers, it appears that neither could talk to each other.  I also tried

```
setParameter:
    auth
```

but MongoDB wouldn't start up with that configuration.

What's the right way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are using a replica set, merely setting `security.authorization` is not sufficient as you need to allow for [cluster members to authenticate](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/security-internal-authentication/#inter-process-auth) which is referred to as "Internal Authentication" in the docs.

The easiest way to do this is using a [keyfile](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/security-internal-authentication/#keyfiles) which is essentially a shared secret/password among the cluster members. After you've created your keyfile and copied it to all of the replica set members, you'll need to specify it's location in your config via the `security.keyFile` setting or using `--keyFile`.

For reference, you may also want to read [Enforce Keyfile Access Control on Existing Replica Set](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/enforce-keyfile-access-control-in-existing-replica-set/#enforce-keyfile-access-control-on-existing-replica-set) for more detail on these steps.